# Azure Easy Tables - How to load items after 15

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

I am looking for solution how to load items from Azure Easy Tables after 15 on each load in Xamarin.Forms app.

I have tried using:

```
int number = 15;
Client.GetTable<Class>().Take(number);
number = number + 15;
```

But it also loads previous items.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the backend returns only the first 50 rows. You can increase the number of returned rows by calling the `Take` method. Use `Take` along with the `Skip` method to request a specific "page" of the total dataset returned by the query.

You could refer to the following code to skips the top 15 items and returns the next 15 items.

```
int number=15;
int number2=15;
Client.GetTable<Class>().Skip(number).Take(number2);
number=number+15;
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#paging).